# An optimization problem over two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, infinite-loop

I have the function `fun[x_,y_, t_] = Cos[x] + Exp[I y] Sin[x] Sin[t];` such that $0\le {\rm x}\le \pi$, $0\le {\rm y}\le 2\pi$, and $0\le {\rm t} \le 10$. I compute the derivative of the real part of this function as `derivativefun[x_,y_, t_] = D[Re[fun[x,y, t]], t];`. Now I want to write the following algorithm to be executed on Mathematica:

Step1: Select a value of `x` and `y` say `x=0` and `y=0`, find `derivativefun[0,0, t]`; Integrate over those intervals of `t` for which `derivativefun[0,0, t]` is positive (The integral will be a function of `t`).

Step2: Select another value of `x` and `y` say `x=0.5` and `y=0.5` find `derivativefun[0.5,0.5, t]`;Integrate over those intervals of `t` for which `derivativefun[0.5,0.5, t]` is positive (again, the integral will be a function of `t`).

Step3: Do the same for the entire range of $0\le {\rm x} \le\pi$ and $0\le {\rm y} \le 2\pi$.

Step4: Finally, choose that integral (as a function of `t`) which is the maximum of all.

To sum up, I need to compute the integral of the derivative of the real part of `fun[x_,y_, t_]`over the range of ${\rm t}$ where the derivative is an increasing function. This is to be done for all values of parameters ${\rm x}$ and ${\rm y}$ within their given ranges. Finally that integral is to be chosen which is the maximum of all.

Edit: The derivative is to be taken of the absolute value of the function `fun[x_,y_, t_]`.

Edit2: Since there are issues with the derivative of the Abs[]. It turns out that real part of the function `fun[x_,y_, t_]` would also work for me. Therefore, I have edited the question, changing Abs[] to Re[].

Comment: Your function is complex, so what does it mean to integrate over the intervals where the function is positive? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, @CarlWoll. It should be the absolute value of the derivative of function. Edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `derivativefun[x_,y_, t_] = D[Abs[fun[x,y, t]], t];` seems to be wrong, because `t` is used as function argument and as variable of differentiation.

Try (avoid use of `Abs[]` because `Abs'[]` isn't defined)

```
derivativefun[x_, y_ ] :=Evaluate[ComplexExpand[D[Sqrt[# Conjugate[#]] &[ fun[x, y, t]], t]]];
```

which gives what you want

```
Plot[derivativefun[1, 0]  , {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The integration (for examplary x,y ) over positive derivative follows to

```
NIntegrate[ Max[0, derivativefun[1, 0] ], {t, 0, 10}]
(*2.52441*)
```

**addendum**

The question changed from `Abs` to `Re`, which simplifies the problem considerably.

real part  of `fun[x_, y_, t_]`

```
D[ComplexExpand[Re[Cos[x] + Exp[I y] Sin[x] Sin[t]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], t]
(*Cos[t] Cos[y] Sin[x]*)

f[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[Max[0, Cos[t] Cos[y] Sin[x]], {t, 0,10}]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

The maximum of this surface is waht you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks, @Ulrich Neumann. It turns out that Re[] would equally work for my problem. Therefore, I have edited the question, replacing Abs[] by Re[].

Comment: That simplifies  the problem considerably!

Comment: Thanks, @Ulrich Neumann. That looks good. However, I want just a 2-D plot, which shows the Integral (for a particular x=x_0 and y=y_0) as a function of t, such that this integral is the maximum from all other integrals (wich are for other values of x and y).

Comment: After integrating `over t` there is no dependancy on `t` anymore! The value of this integral is plotted in my answer.

Comment: Can't one talk about the indefinite integral here? I mean without giving limits?

Comment: That means the scope of your question changes again?

Comment: Sorry, but I had repeatedly mentioned in my question that "The integral will be a function of t".

Comment: Please clarify "The integral will be a function of t". I don't think that this can be true after integrating over t.

Comment: Integrating Cos[t], for example, gives Sin[t]-a function of t.

Comment: ... I don't think that this can be true after integrating over the range of t. (as mentioned in your question sum up)

Comment: thanks for your time. Really appreciate it. However, I am sure that indefinite integration (=integrating without putting limits) can be performed.

Comment: Thank you too for the dialogue.  Still I doubt how to handle the indefinite integration of "positive derivative".